# How to make a styled circle component using tailwindcss?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on image upload component in my react app and I design the image uploader component.

Here is the code and the result respectively.

```
<div className="px-8 py-6 mt-2 text-left bg-white shadow-lg">
        <form action="">
          <div class="flex  items-center justify-center bg-grey-lighter">
            <label class=" flex flex-col items-center px-4 py-6 bg-white text-blue rounded-lg shadow-lg tracking-wide uppercase border border-blue cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue hover:text-white">
              <AddAPhotoIcon />
              <span class="mt-2 text-base leading-normal">Upload Photo</span>
              <input type="file" class="hidden" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

[image]

But I want change it exactly as the following component.

[image]

Comment: well it's quite easy but what have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the same width and height for the element you want circular, in combination with `rounded-full`.

I adapted your example and used `h-40` and `w-40` to control height and width. With `rounded-full`, the result is a circular component.

```html
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <form action="">
    <label class="text-blue border-blue hover:bg-blue flex h-40 w-40 cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-full border bg-white uppercase tracking-wide shadow-lg hover:text-white">
      <AddAPhotoIcon />
      <span class="mt-2 text-base leading-normal">Upload Photo</span>
      <input type="file" class="hidden" />
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: at least encourage developers to what they have tried so far don't just answer their question

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want ??

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="p-10 w-72 border-4 border-gray-200 rounded-full">
  <div class="bg-gray-300 p-20 w-52 rounded-full text-center">
    Upload <br/>Photo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <img
    src={`${backend_url}${i.image}`} // source of your image
    alt="black chair and white table"
    className="object-container object-center bg-white rounded-full w-40 
    h-40 border bg-white"
   />
```